# µTorrent : how to change the 30 minute timeout of trackers

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I want to change the tracker timeout in µTorrent from 30 minutes to something else (Preferably more than 30 minutes)...

But I can't seem to find an option or switch for it...

is there any way to change the timeout ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't**.

That parameter is controlled by the [Tracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_tracker).

And it's not a '**Timeout**', it's a '**Interval**' how often the client announces to the tracker.
To often causes unnecessary loads.
To seldom and the peer gets removed form the trackers peer list.

Comment: I would have upvoted you, but I'm not reputable enough ! Thanks !

Comment: @Cypher ill do for both, this is the answer, short and clear.